# Is there a recommendation for graphics card for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: graphics, video, gpu

I want to build my own computer to run Ubuntu 12.10. What are your recommendations for graphics card brands that work best with 12.10?

Comment: As per the FAQ - shopping recommendations are off-topic - there are too broad to be answered with a definitive answer.